# How to make delete button in Django

Tags: python, django

Help me please to understand how to make the delete button, its must to delete a `Cat`

```
class Cat(models.Model):
    class Meta():
        db_table = "cat"

    paw = models.IntegerField(default=4)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, default='Cat')
    age = models.IntegerField(default=False, null=False)
    species = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    hairiness = models.IntegerField(default=False, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

This is my `views.py`, hope you can help. (it's need for my job interview on Monday)

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Cat
from .forms import CatForm
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def home(request):
    template = "base.html"
    queryset = Cat.objects.all()
    context = {
        "object_list": queryset
    }
    return render(request, template, context)

def new_cat(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CatForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cat = form.save(commit=False)
            cat.save()
            return redirect('/', pk=cat.pk)
    else:
        form = CatForm()
    return render(request, 'new_cat.html', {'form': form})

def cat_edit(request, pk):
    cat = get_object_or_404(Cat, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CatForm(request.POST, instance=cat)
        if form.is_valid():
            cat = form.save(commit=False)
            cat.save()
            return redirect('/', pk=cat.pk)
    else:
        form = CatForm(instance=cat)
    return render(request, 'new_cat.html', {'form': form})
```

site is asc to addd more details, but i just don't know what else, i can add.

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^new/$', views.new_cat, name='new_cat'),
    url(r'^edit/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.cat_edit, name='cat_edit'),
]
```

Comment: you can try do the same as your `cat_edit`, show you view, please

Answer (score 20, accepted):

At first, you should create a `cat_delete` view, which should look something like this:

```
def cat_delete(request, pk):
    cat = get_object_or_404(Cat, pk=pk)  # Get your current cat

    if request.method == 'POST':         # If method is POST,
        cat.delete()                     # delete the cat.
        return redirect('/')             # Finally, redirect to the homepage.

    return render(request, 'template_name.html', {'cat': cat})
    # If method is not POST, render the default template.
    # *Note*: Replace 'template_name.html' with your corresponding template name.
```

Then, you should map this view in your `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = 'cats'
# Note that app_name is added here!
# It is used as a namespace in order to reverse your urls better.
# See usage in template.

urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    url(r'^delete/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.cat_delete, name='cat_delete')
]
```

In your template, you should create a form with *delete button*, which will simply send a *POST* request to the delete view:

```
<form action="{% url 'cats:cat_delete' cat.id %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" value="Delete cat">
</form>
```

Look closely on the form's **action**:

```
{% url 'cats:cat_delete' cat.id %}
```

Here I am using the `app_name` from `urls.py` that I previously added in order to resolve your urls by name, not by path. Now `cats:cat_delete` will evaluate to `cats/delete/<pk>`. And of course you pass the `cat.id`.

This should do the trick with deleting instance of your `Cat` model. Hope I helped.

Comment: Thank you very much, for your help and really big answer, now i understand my mistake))