# Is there any hazards of using HTTP post method instead of DELETE

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, express, http

I'm creating a TODO list app with nodejs and I need an option to delete a todo record. So I've created an HTML form that contains a delete button but I can only use POST as the method. actually my code is working fine but are there any problems with using POST to DELETE records?

Comment: So does it explained your questions?

Answer (score 2):

No there isn't. Apart from `GET` and `POST` requests, most of the other HTTP method serve only semantic purposes. Except for some notable examples such as `OPTIONS` which is use to communicate supported methods. Using correct HTTP verbs will make your application / API easier to understand.

The same goes for HTTP status code. Functionality-wise, it doesn't really matter if you send a 200 (OK), 201(Created), or 202 (Accepted) for a successful request. However, sending the correct status code can avoid necessary confusion.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, no. There're no hazards of using HTTP post method instead of DELETE. You can see how it's used in deletion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46003056/how-to-make-delete-button-in-django)

Comment: If any more doubts about Django/DRF/MERN, you can ask me without hesistation

Answer (score 0):

One difference is that users might be tricked into making the POST request and inadvertently deleting an entry, if they are lured onto a malicious web page that contains an auto-submitting HTML form

```
<form method="POST" action="<your deletion endpoint>">
```

(Whether that is possible depends on the content type that your deletion endpoint expects.)

A DELETE request, however, cannot be forged in such a way. A malicious web page could create a DELETE request only with `fetch` or `XMLHttpRequest`, and because of the CORS protocol the browser would refuse to carry that out (unless your server explicitly allows it through a suitable [CORS preflight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) response).